# Closed form for the following integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

As part of my research and my calculations I got the following integrals. Do they have a closed form. Any help is appreciated:

$$\int\limits_{x,y\in [0,1]^n}{\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{\|x-y\|}}dxdy$$
$$\int\limits_{x,y\in [0,1]^n}{\frac{|x_i^2-y_i^2|}{\|x-y\|}}dxdy$$

Where $\|\cdot\|$ is eucliadian norm and $x_i$ and $y_i$ are $i$-th coordinates where $i$ is arbitrary index of the $n$-dimensional vectors.

UPDATE:
Thanks to @achillehui, I forgot to put absoute value signs.

Comment: They are zero if the integral is over all $n$ dimensions. The integrand is odd under the change of variables $x \leftrightarrow y$.

Comment: Oops! I forgot the abs brackets!